# not able to conect nodes in the compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, selection-tools, select

I'm having a weird problem, I've had it before but at the moment I'm using the compositor so much that it's getting really annoying...
at the moment I'm working in 2.82a but I've had this problem in al the versions before that one.

I'm unable to connect nodes by hand (see gif)

[image]

I am however able to do it with noderangler, but when I do that the connection starts at another point (see give)

[image]

it's also just really hard to select nodes (with a mouse and with my Wacom), sometimes when I click on the nodes or use box select I select the node next to it or just nothing at all. (see gif)

[image]

this also makes me unable to use frames because I'm probably dragging nodes "next" to them instead of on top of them...

This all points to the nodes actually being in a different place than they are being shown to me. Do you guys have any ideas on how to fix this? 
As is sat I've tried different versions, restarting the program and my laptop and I don't have any other ideas.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It looks like having two areas of the interface displaying nodes is causing this bug.
Just close the other nodes area(s) and it should be back to normal. It worked for me !